# Stuck messegs in Websphere QM

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I'm working with websphere 7.3 & my Queue manager works fine, but i have an issue as some tries stuck in the queue, but if i retried it again it passes. My Channels on my Target QM is Running in both Sides, also the size of the Msgs is smaller that the allowed "2.3M or even 120k".

Comment: Please include additional information. Share your code where you push the messages into the queue. Are you seeing any errors? What about the logs?

Comment: unfortunately ,  no errors in logs, just the MSG in the local queue file only, no errors just a TImeout exception

Comment: Edit your question and include the timeout exception.

Comment: When you say it is "stuck in the queue" - could you describe how you know that - what do you see and where to indicate it is stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, 
Really as it's a strange behavior of the QM, i can't really provide more INFO
but i managed to Solve it as i found an other QM in the target QM Cluster pile up as some one define the same QL on it so all request targeted it , so Pile up, 
i cleared the created QL on it , then restart the target Cluster & it works